# Do people actually still use cin and cout?

Tags: c++

This is totally an opinion question.  More for chatter. 
I'm taking some c++ tests and they are littered with cin and cout's.
Do people acutally still use these.  I mean I've not seen one in an actual public application ever.

The last question I answered in a test was

```
int c1;
cout << "Enter numbers: " << flush;
for(int n = 0; cin >> c1; ++n){
   cout << c1 << endl;
}
When does this end..
```

The correct answer was "when a user hits ctrl+Z".   Where in the heck would I press control+Z? I'm assuming in the terminal, I suppose.  But honestly.  I've not seen the terminal for ages and ages.  And I'm sure as heck not going to attempt to program anything for it.

Are questions like this still relevant, in any of our lives?

Comment: You're a programmer and you haven't used a command line in ages?

Comment: The problem with "When a user hits Ctrl+Z" is it's specific to console input on Windows. If the answer is changed to "When the standard input stream reaches end-of-file or encounters an error," then this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Ah! Maybe that's why people can't pass my job interviews questions like "print out this word backwards". They simply DONT KNOW HOW TO PRINT!

Comment: I believe it's CTRL+D on a linux console.

Comment: Palm doesn't have a command line.  so no I've not used it..  Pocket PC's, phones, and embedded devices.  How about Jet planes.  Not much use for a terminal. Windows app.. no command line.  word processor apps, web apps, I've run out of text in the comment.  Most apps don't ever touch the terminal.

Comment: I will (after reading these posts) admit, that many many do.  But there are hundreds upon thousands of apps that never do touch the terminal. And to imagin that a programer who doesn't use it is somehow not a programer assumes facts not in evidence.   PS. typing here is not in the terminal. :)

Comment: how in the world is displaying text on a screen printing it? it's displaying it.. AfxMessageBox("displaying"), "prints" the text. How about fwrite to save it to a file. Or write to save it to a CFile. Can you "print" on a palm? No? You must be a crappy c++ programmer. :) Bad assumption? Yes!!!

Comment: That loop is horrible! The variable `n` is completely useless. Since that `for` only uses its end condition, it should be a `while`.

Please smack your teacher for me

Comment: This is actually a very good question (the OP's, not the test question).  It concerns both the relevance of console applications in a modern world and the relevance of teaching the aging C++ iostreams library.  The reality is that different platforms emphasize different working models and therefore these tools are more relevant for some than for others.

Comment: cin is mainly used as `getline(cin);`

Answer (score 22):

Terminals are widely used, and will be used. The reason is that, when used skillfully, they're far more powerful than any GUIs.

Comment: It was an generalization and with a hint of flamebait ;-) Obviously in some cases GUIs are more appropriate - for example, in graphic design work. But then, a well-written shell command combination typed in few seconds can replace dozens of mouse clicks and drags in some cases.

Comment: I take the bait. :) to that.. a well written menu and short cut keys in a GUI can remove the clicks all together.. ctrl+s saves in most apps. pressing f7 in VS saves all and compiles.  do that in one key stroke in any terminal.

Comment: I guess you could create a shell alias (e.g. 'a+enter') that does that, and whatever else you wish. How about (copied from elsewhere) creating a list of all the unique package names imported by your Java code?" grep '^import ' *.java | sed -e's/.*import  *//' | -e's/;.*$//' | sort -u >list ;-)

Answer (score 12):

No, such questions are not very relevant, but yes, people use std::cin and std::cout all the time. Even the ones who design graphical interfaces may use cout for debugging !

Comment: Good on you. I use TRACE because it's not compiled in the release.. but it's good to see why others would use it.

Comment: having logging macros that have their implementations wrapped in debug if-defs avoid them being compiled into the release. and can be used for a multitude of purposes, i.e logging across the network, into file, into output windows, graphical console etc etc

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as long as console applications exist, cout and cin will exist.

Answer (score 6):

So you want to say that you are a programmer and never used or wrote console application?

Comment: Not once since university.  Mind you I'm mostly in the PDA world.  But I don't even remember the last time I went to the console in windows.  Not to do anything serious.

Comment: Windows and Linux provide vastly different console facilities.  If you were using Linux as your desktop, you would be more likely to find uses for the console -- and therefore be more likely to use cin/cout/cerr.

Comment: and more likely to get the question wrong as ctrl+z doesn't work in linux.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it's relevant.

Many automation and admin scripts on a variety of servers rely on text output/input, for example. This is especially true on *nix systems, not as much on windows now that Powershell has come about with its fancy object support.

Then there are the ones of us (a dying breed, I admit) that pretty much LIVE in the terminal. I use the terminal for about 70-80% of my work. I just find it more natural, faster and more powerful than most related GUI apps.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you might want to process or transform an input text file. It'll prove handy.

Comment: Excellent answer.. I'd not likely use cin to do that.. but excellent answer. Ps  CFile::read  || fread(FILEPTR,...) would be my likely choice. But that's just because of my exprience.  c++ is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, to write a complex piece of software, it is a good approach to **separate the GUI** from the rest, i.e., in general, the rest must be ***able to work even without the GUI***.

In this case it can be convenient to manage I/O with cin/cout.

Comment: That's excellent.. So on a palm with no cmd window, and no file system where would cout go?  Where would cin come from on a bluetooth device with no keyboard and no screen?

Comment: I should add, that I voted you up.. You gave a good example of when it's good to use.  It's not something I can ever use, but it is a good use. :)

Comment: I have never touched a Palm, but I would bet it has a file system. So you can redirect cin/cout to a file. If, on the other side, your device has no file system, no keyboard, no display, ... maybe you can create a virtual file system in memory. What? It's got no memory either? - At this point your only option is to try to resell your device on EBay... ;-)

Comment: In general, streams are useful because they provide a standard interface which is independent from the input/output device you may use. You can switch at run time from the console to the file system, or whatever.

Comment: actually palms (in days gone by) relied on a database system.. Even applications were just a record in a name spaced (sort of) database. I'm over simplifying it.. I agree with the mixed MVC though.. it is definitely a best practice to strive for it.

Answer (score 2):

> Do people acutally still use these. I mean I've not seen one in an actual public application ever.

Define public application. What do you think the command line tools on any *nix use? And yes, we too use them, for our SDKs (at least cout and cerr). `cin` is often not the best when you have complex enough input -- you are left to write a lexer and a parser of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever write GUI or Web applications in your career you probably won't have much use for cin and cout.  If you ever write anything embedded you'll change your position.  You just use a different set of libraries for console apps, text-based apps, GUI apps, and Web apps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use wcin and wcout, at least you get the Unicode stuff.

Comment: AFAIK, that's a non-portable windows c++ only concept.  other systems (and languages/libraries) simply define that stdin/stdout take bytes and should be adequately encoded (usually ASCII or UTF-8)

Comment: Not according to ISO/IEC 14882:2003 section 27.3.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on many professional applications and we've not used cin or cout on any of them, even for logging/debugging.  Why?  Because the stateless *printf methods work perfectly well.  One thing I've learned over the years is that stateless trumps statefull for maintainability.

Comment: It's true that the state "facilities" provided by iostreams are horrible, especially the inability to save/restore all state in a RAII way. OTOH, they're great for when the types of values may change (e.g. in templates) and you won't ever get problems like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601180

Answer (score 1):

It would be more acceptable, from a language standpoint, if the answer to "when will this program end" was "when EOF is received". Just because "Control-Z" is EOF in DOS, does not mean Ctrl-Z is the right answer.

**Edit**
Edited with comment info.

Comment: @Doug: No, it would be more acceptable to answer "When the standard input stream reaches end-of-file."  End-of-file is a language concept.

Comment: Looking at the "for", it ends when "cin >> c1" evaluates to false. But I never use expressions which combine command and query in a boolean condition.

Comment: ^Z is the DOS style of sending an end of file marker.  It effectively terminates 'cin', causing the loop to break by returning false.

Comment: Well.. If I saw this code. I'd want to smack the person who wrote it.. for's are counters, whiles are undefined.  And agree about the EOF. Sadly it was multiple choice.

Comment: @Daniel: That's a good rule of thumb as it usually improves code clarity.  But IMHO there are times when combining "action" and "query" leads to clearer code, and (again IMHO) this is one of them.

Comment: On a Linux system, EOF is Ctrl+D, if I recall it correctly. Plus if you're using a pipe or a redirection as that mini-app's input, it will end when the input stream is closed (there's nothing more to read).

Comment: (The last comment applies for any system which supports redirection, which includes even most versions of DOS)

Answer (score 0):

I use std::cin, std::cout and std::cerr daily. Systems programming lacks GUIs.